# Does Unity animation event send a message to every object which owns it?

Tags: unity, animation

I made game objects A, B. And each has animator, and it has the same animation. And they are inherited class of Base class.

I trigger animation on A object, and the animation has callback and invoke it when the animation ends. The callback sets bool value true.

My expectation was, the callback will only change bool value in A. But bool value in B was changed. Is this natural?

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public bool triggered;
}

public class A : BaseClass
{
    public void OnAnimEnd()
    {
        triggered = true;
    }
}

public class B : BaseClass
{
    public void OnAnimEnd()
    {
        triggered = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not how (non-static) C# variables nor animation events work - there's likely another factor here that's making it appear as though setting a class A instance's triggered variable also set it on an instance of class B. Can you walk us through the complete steps to reproduce this problem so we can help you track down the confounding factor?

Comment: @DMGregory um,, you mean the animation event triggered in A class should not effect to B class. right?

Comment: An animation triggered on instance X should not affect instance Y, whether they're the same class or different classes doesn't matter.

Comment: @DMGregory oops. i registered A and B's event handler to object C and animation callback invoke it. so both of it changed.,, thank you for your advise.

Comment: No worries. Just next time, if you want to ask "Does Unity do this thing that seems silly?" please remember to stop and check "Wait, did I tell Unity to do this thing?" - a surprising number of these questions turn out this way. ;) If you like, you can share your solution as an Answer below, or we can put the question on hold - whichever you'd prefer.

Answer (score 1):

An animation triggered on instance X should not affect instance Y, whether they're the same class or different classes doesn't matter.